# Youtube panel tabs on tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

If you take a look at the Youtube app for tablet devices, you'll see a panel at the top consisting of 3 tabs. When user switches between those it doesn't seem like the overall activity is changed: the panel doesn't flicker but the view below it changes.

How is it done ? Does it mean they use a single activity for all 3 tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is actually one but there is a [Tab Host View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) which can achieve that.

It acts as a parent activity and handles the tab-views as children

Comment: probably, but I don't think it's a good idea to make a single activity instead of 4-5 dedicated to each purpose. Do you know a way of making use of tab Host + activities as tabs ? I mean, what will happen with GC and how am I supposed to organize all this logic ?

Comment: look at the sample. Each tab is a single activity, the tabs are managed in a 4th "parent" activity. So these 3 tabs behave like a mini-app inside the TabView panel. I think it's the best way to go for tabbed apps.

Comment: uhm, right - it's, probably, still not the right way to go since the class is deprecated http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html. I can try implementing it with fragments though. thanks for the suggestions. Ill keep topic opened for a while in case someone has anything to complement.